# How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

If I have a function which accepts more than one string parameter, the first parameter seems to get all the data assigned to it, and remaining parameters are passed in as empty.

A quick test script:

```
Function Test([string]$arg1, [string]$arg2)
{
    Write-Host "`$arg1 value: $arg1"
    Write-Host "`$arg2 value: $arg2"
}

Test("ABC", "DEF")
```

The output generated is

```
$arg1 value: ABC DEF
$arg2 value:
```

The correct output should be:

```
$arg1 value: ABC
$arg2 value: DEF
```

This seems to be consistent between v1 and v2 on multiple machines, so obviously, I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone point out exactly what?

Comment: You just call like this: `Test "ABC" "DEF"`

Comment: IMHO the fact that this question and answer has so many upvotes goes to show that the current implementation is.... not intuitive.

Answer (score 751, accepted):

Parameters in calls to functions in PowerShell (all versions) **are space-separated, not comma separated**. Also, the parentheses are entirely unneccessary and will cause a parse error in PowerShell 2.0 (or later) if [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-6) `-Version 2` or higher is active. Parenthesised arguments are used in .NET methods only.

```
function foo($a, $b, $c) {
   "a: $a; b: $b; c: $c"
}

ps> foo 1 2 3
a: 1; b: 2; c: 3
```

Comment: Most important thing that has finally helped 'stick' this in my mind is the last sentence: "Parenthesised arguments are used in .NET Methods only."

Comment: I prefer using the paranthesis and comma separated.. is it possible to do this in powershell?

Comment: @samyi No. Passing a `(1,2,3)` to a function is effectively treated as an array; a single argument. If you want to use OO method style arguments, use modules: `$m = new-module -ascustomobject { function Add($x,$y) { $x + $y } }; $m.Add(1,1)`

Comment: `Powershell` is a shell language and it's common for shell languages to use spaces as a token separator. I wouldn't say `Powershell` is being different here, it's right in line with other system default shells like `cmd`, `sh`, `bash`, etc.

Comment: this seems to be different for object method calls such as $var.method($var1,$var2). i get a syntax error if i remove the comma. what's going on here?

Comment: @ShayanZafar as I said in my original post, that syntax is for .NET framework calls. Only Native powershell functions/cmdlets use spaces.

Comment: This is unfortunate. The latest pwsh can look close to a normal programming language, invoking methods the way we used to would be awesome.

Comment: @serj - but it's a scripting language - space-separated arguments are the norm for shell languages, as codewario says above.

Comment: Just trying PowerShell and my mind is tricking me to use Java syntax everywhere!!! If possible I would give 1000 votes to this answer

Comment: IMHO the fact that this question and answer has so many upvotes goes to show that the current implementation is.... not intuitive.

Answer (score 345):

The correct answer has already been provided, but this issue seems prevalent enough to warrant some additional details for those wanting to understand the subtleties.

I would have added this just as a comment, but I wanted to include an illustration--I tore this off my quick reference chart on PowerShell functions. This assumes function f's signature is `f($a, $b, $c)`:

[image: Syntax pitfalls of a function call]

Thus, one can call a function with space-separated *positional* parameters or order-independent *named* parameters. The other pitfalls reveal that you need to be cognizant of commas, parentheses, *and* white space.

For further reading, see my article *[Down the Rabbit Hole: A Study in PowerShell Pipelines, Functions, and Parameters](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/)*. The article contains a link to the quick reference/wall chart as well.

Answer (score 102):

There are some good answers here, but I wanted to point out a couple of other things. Function parameters are actually a place where PowerShell shines. For example, you can have either named or positional parameters in advanced functions like so:

```
function Get-Something
{
    Param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
         [string] $Name,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
         [int] $Id
    )
}
```

Then you could either call it by specifying the parameter name, or you could just use positional parameters, since you explicitly defined them. So either of these would work:

```
Get-Something -Id 34 -Name "Blah"
Get-Something "Blah" 34
```

The first example works even though `Name` is provided second, because we explicitly used the parameter name. The second example works based on position though, so `Name` would need to be first. When possible, I always try to define positions so both options are available.

PowerShell also has the ability to define parameter sets. It uses this in place of method overloading, and again is quite useful:

```
function Get-Something
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Name')]
    Param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ParameterSetName='Name')]
         [string] $Name,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ParameterSetName='Id')]
         [int] $Id
    )
}
```

Now the function will either take a name, or an id, but not both.  You can use them positionally, or by name. Since they are a different type, PowerShell will figure it out. So all of these would work:

```
Get-Something "some name"
Get-Something 23
Get-Something -Name "some name"
Get-Something -Id 23
```

You can also assign additional parameters to the various parameter sets. (That was a pretty basic example obviously.) Inside of the function, you can determine which parameter set was used with the $PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName property. For example:

```
if($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "Name")
{
    Write-Host "Doing something with name here"
}
```

Then, on a related side note, there is also parameter validation in PowerShell. This is one of my favorite PowerShell features, and it makes the code inside your functions very clean. There are numerous validations you can use. A couple of examples are:

```
function Get-Something
{
    Param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
         [ValidatePattern('^Some.*')]
         [string] $Name,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
         [ValidateRange(10,100)]
         [int] $Id
    )
}
```

In the first example, ValidatePattern accepts a regular expression that assures the supplied parameter matches what you're expecting.  If it doesn't, an intuitive exception is thrown, telling you exactly what is wrong. So in that example, 'Something' would work fine, but 'Summer' wouldn't pass validation.

ValidateRange ensures that the parameter value is in between the range you expect for an integer. So 10 or 99 would work, but 101 would throw an exception.

Another useful one is ValidateSet, which allows you to explicitly define an array of acceptable values. If something else is entered, an exception will be thrown. There are others as well, but probably *the most useful* one is ValidateScript. This takes a script block that must evaluate to $true, so the sky is the limit. For example:

```
function Get-Something
{
    Param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
         [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf' })]
         [ValidateScript({ (Get-Item $_ | select -Expand Extension) -eq ".csv" })]
         [string] $Path
    )
}
```

In this example, we are assured not only that $Path exists, but that it is a file, (as opposed to a directory) and has a .csv extension. ($_ refers to the parameter, when inside your scriptblock.) You can also pass in much larger, multi-line script blocks if that level is required, or use multiple scriptblocks like I did here. It's extremely useful and makes for nice clean functions and intuitive exceptions.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating `My_Function -NamedParamater "ParamValue"` function call style. This is a pattern that more PS script code should follow for readability.

Comment: Is it a typo to have two `Position=0` ?

Comment: No it's not a typo.  That would be the case when you're using parameter sets, which are basically just method overloads. So in that case either `name` OR `id` could be passed, but not both.  Since both are position 0,  PowerShell will figure out which one you're using based on the type, if you don't specify the parameter name. (One is `int` and one is `string`)

Answer (score 58):

You call PowerShell functions without the parentheses and without using the comma as a separator. Try using:

```
test "ABC" "DEF"
```

In PowerShell the comma (,) is an array operator, e.g.

```
$a = "one", "two", "three"
```

It sets `$a` to an array with three values.

Answer (score 22):

```
Function Test([string]$arg1, [string]$arg2)
{
    Write-Host "`$arg1 value: $arg1"
    Write-Host "`$arg2 value: $arg2"
}

Test "ABC" "DEF"
```

Answer (score 17):

Because this is a frequent viewed question, I want to mention that a PowerShell function should use [approved verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) (**Verb-Noun** as the function name).
The verb part of the name identifies the action that the cmdlet performs. The noun part of the name identifies the entity on which the action is performed. This rule *simplifies* the usage of your cmdlets for advanced PowerShell users.

Also, you can specify things like whether the parameter is *mandatory* and the *position* of the parameter:

```
function Test-Script
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string]$arg1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$arg2
    )

    Write-Host "`$arg1 value: $arg1"
    Write-Host "`$arg2 value: $arg2"
}
```

---

To pass the parameter to the function you can either use the **position**:

```
Test-Script "Hello" "World"
```

Or you *specify* the parameter **name**:

```
Test-Script -arg1 "Hello" -arg2 "World"
```

You **don't use parentheses** like you do when you call a function within C#.

---

I would recommend to *always* pass the parameter names when using more than one parameter, since this is more *readable*.

Comment: FYI, approved verbs list link no longer works, but can now be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands

Comment: @KeithLangmead Thank you Keith, I updated my answer as well.

Comment: "Verb-Noun" as in both verb and noun capitalised? Perhaps change the answer to be more explicit about it?

Comment: I've never understood the "you should use **approved** verbs" argument. I'm not contesting the `Verb-Noun` nomenclature, but what (possibly obscure as I've never run into a problem) issues would I run into with the example function name `Setup-Node` vs. `Initialize-Node` or `Bootstrap-Node`?

Comment: well, consider you expose a `Get-Node` cmdlet. It would be clear for us that we have to invoke `Get-Node`, not `Retrieve-Node`, nor `Receive-Node`, nor .....

Comment: Also meaningfull to add the `[Alias('something')]` before the Param() section. This allows the use of non-verb-approved functions (like eg. gci, ls, dir, cd ...). Example: `function Test-Script {
[CmdletBinding()]
[Alias('tst')] 
Param()
Write-Output "This function works."}`

Answer (score 14):

If you're a C# / Java / C++ / Ruby / Python / Pick-A-Language-From-This-Century developer and you want to call your function with commas, because that's what you've always done, then you need something like this:

```
$myModule = New-Module -ascustomobject { 
    function test($arg1, $arg2) { 
        echo "arg1 = $arg1, and arg2 = $arg2"
    }
}
```

Now call:

```
$myModule.test("ABC", "DEF")
```

and you'll see

```
arg1 = ABC, and arg2 = DEF
```

Comment: Java, C++, Ruby, and Python are not from this century (only C#), presuming the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) (though some have evolved more than others).

Comment: Heh. @PeterMortensen your argument is that I should say "Pick a language from either this century or the last one"?  :-)

Answer (score 12):

If you don't know (or care) how many arguments you will be passing to the function, you could also use a very simple approach like;

**Code**:

```
function FunctionName()
{
    Write-Host $args
}
```

That would print out all arguments. For example:

```
FunctionName a b c 1 2 3
```

**Output**

```
a b c 1 2 3
```

I find this particularly useful when creating functions that use external commands that could have many different (and optional) parameters, but relies on said command to provide feedback on syntax errors, etc.

Here is a another real-world example (creating a function to the tracert command, which I hate having to remember the truncated name);

**Code**:

```
Function traceroute
{
    Start-Process -FilePath "$env:systemroot\system32\tracert.exe" -ArgumentList $args -NoNewWindow
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you try:

```
PS > Test("ABC", "GHI") ("DEF")
```

you get:

```
$arg1 value: ABC GHI
$arg2 value: DEF
```

So you see that the parentheses separates the parameters

---

If you try:

```
PS > $var = "C"
PS > Test ("AB" + $var) "DEF"
```

you get:

```
$arg1 value: ABC
$arg2 value: DEF
```

Now you could find some immediate usefulness of the parentheses - a space will not become a separator for the next parameter - instead you have an eval function.

Comment: Parens don't separate parameters. They define array.

Comment: Parens don't define an array, they define a group, which powershell can interpret as an array. Arrays are defined with an at sign (`@`) before the leading paren, like this empty array: `@()`; or this array with two numbers: `@(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see it mentioned here, but [**splatting**](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/splatting/#Introduction_to_PowerShell_Splatting) your arguments is a useful alternative and becomes especially useful if you are building out the arguments to a command dynamically (as opposed to using `Invoke-Expression`). You can splat with arrays for positional arguments and hashtables for named arguments. Here are some examples:

> **Note:** You can use positional splats with external commands arguments with relative ease, but named splats are less useful with external commands. They work, but the program must accept arguments in the `-Key:Value` format as each parameter relates to the hashtable key/value pairs. One example of such software is the `choco` command from the Chocolatey package manager for Windows.

### Splat With Arrays (Positional Arguments)

#### Test-Connection with Positional Arguments

```
Test-Connection www.google.com localhost
```

#### With Array Splatting

```
$argumentArray = 'www.google.com', 'localhost'
Test-Connection @argumentArray
```

> Note that when splatting, we reference the splatted variable with an `@` instead of a `$`. It is the same when using a Hashtable to splat as well.

### Splat With Hashtable (Named Arguments)

#### Test-Connection with Named Arguments

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName www.google.com -Source localhost
```

#### With Hashtable Splatting

```
$argumentHash = @{
  ComputerName = 'www.google.com'
  Source = 'localhost'
}
Test-Connection @argumentHash
```

### Splat Positional and Named Arguments Simultaneously

#### Test-Connection With Both Positional and Named Arguments

```
Test-Connection www.google.com localhost -Count 1
```

#### Splatting Array and Hashtables Together

```
$argumentHash = @{
  Count = 1
}
$argumentArray = 'www.google.com', 'localhost'
Test-Connection @argumentHash @argumentArray
```

Comment: This did not work for me but I did something like this instead $Results = GetServerInformation $Servers $ServerNames

Comment: Splatting is the syntax used to take a hashtable or array and unroll those as named arguments or positional arguments to another command, as opposed to passing the arguments directly to the command as you have done. If you post a question about your splat not working someone may be able to shed some light on your particular issue.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you're doing with the function, but have a look at using the 'param' keyword. It's quite a bit more powerful for passing parameters into a function, and makes it more user friendly. Below is a link to an overly complex article from Microsoft about it. It isn't as complicated as the article makes it sound.

*[Param Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd347600(v=technet.10))*

Also, here is an example from [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252335/send-mail-via-gmail-with-powershell-v2s-send-mailmessage) on this site:

Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I was having issues when calling the function. Didn't matter if the function was declared with param or without it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Function Test([string]$arg1, [string]$arg2)
{
    Write-Host "`$arg1 value: $arg1"
    Write-Host "`$arg2 value: $arg2"
}

Test("ABC") ("DEF")
```

Answer (score 3):

I stated the following earlier:

The common problem is using the singular form `$arg`, which is incorrect. It should always be plural as `$args`.

The problem is not that.  In fact, `$arg` can be anything else. The problem was the use of the comma and the parentheses.

I run the following code that worked and the output follows:

**Code:**

```
Function Test([string]$var1, [string]$var2)
{
    Write-Host "`$var1 value: $var1"
    Write-Host "`$var2 value: $var2"
}
```

Test "ABC" "DEF"

**Output:**

```
$var1 value: ABC
$var2 value: DEF
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, however, you're a couple of years late :-) The top three answers here had sufficiently addressed the issue. May I suggest heading over to Unanswered section and trying some of those questions?

Answer (score 2):

```
Function Test {
    Param([string]$arg1, [string]$arg2)

    Write-Host $arg1
    Write-Host $arg2
}
```

This is a proper `params` declaration.

See *[about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347600.aspx)*.

And it indeed works.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass **parameters** in a **function** like this also:

```
function FunctionName()
{
    Param ([string]$ParamName);
    # Operations
}
```

Comment: That would be defining parameters for a function, the original question was about how to specify parameters when you call the function.