# Add users to Local User Group

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using following function to add Users to local user group.I need to Add an array of users to a local group on my machine.

```
function AddUsersToGroup([string]$MachineName,[string]$GroupName,[String[]]$Userarr)
{
    write-host 'write: $Userarr'
    Foreach($s in $Userarr)
    {
        write-host $s
    }
    $objOU = [ADSI]"WinNT://$MachineName/$GroupName,group"  
    Foreach($User in $Userarr)
    {
        $objOU.add("WinNT://$MachineName/$User,user")
    }  
} 

$UserArray=@("Administrator", "NETWORK SERVICE", "LOCAL SERVICE","SYSTEM")
AddUsersToGroup -MachineName:"localhost" -GroupName:"Comserver Consumer",-Userarr:@("Administrator", "NETWORK SERVICE", "LOCAL SERVICE","SYSTEM")
AddUsersToGroup -MachineName:"localhost" -GroupName:"Comserver Consumer",-Userarr:@("Administrator", "NETWORK SERVICE", "LOCAL SERVICE","SYSTEM")
```

I am getting the following error:

> The following exception occurred while retrieving member "add":
>   The group name could not be found.

I am new to powershell. Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here

```
-GroupName:"Comserver Consumer", -Userarr
```

A comma is for powershell the delimiter for an array.

The problem you had was, that you seperatet the parameters which a comma, but PowerShell makes it which space.

Take a look to this Question for more informations:
[How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/powershell-multiple-function-parameters)

/Update

Here is the Code

```
function AddUsersToGroup([string]$MachineName,[string]$GroupName,[Array]$Users)
{


    $Group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$MachineName/$GroupName,group"   


    Foreach($User in $Users)
    {
        Write-Host $User
        $Group.Add("WinNT://$User,user")    
    }  
} 


[Array]$UserArray=@("Username", "NETWORK SERVICE", "LOCAL SERVICE","SYSTEM")
AddUsersToGroup -MachineName "localhost" -GroupName "Testgroup" -Users $UserArray
```

Please try it out

Comment: @user1595214 Update is here :)

Comment: feel free to accept my answer when the code works and if it doesn't , please let me in touch, I'll help you