# Pass a Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList to a function

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I'm pretty new to powershell & sharepoint and i'm having hard time trying to create a function.

I'm trying to make a generic function to add new items into a SPList but i can't pass the SPList to the function.

Here is my function prototype:

```
function Add-IntoList([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList] $List,[hashtable] $Columns)
{
... some code
}
```

And here is my call to the function:

```
$web = Get-Web("http://some_url/sandbox1") #It returns the Get-SPWeb
$test = @{"Title" = "Olympia"; "Body" = "Salem"}
Add-IntoList($web.Lists["Announcements"], $test)
```

And it doesn't work, i can't see why.
Here is the error powershell tells me:

```
Add-IntoList : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'List'. Cannnot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPList".
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance,
Nicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the function, instead of calling it like:

```
Add-IntoList($web.Lists["Announcements"], $test)
```

call it like:

```
Add-IntoList $web.Lists["Announcements"] $test
```

Comment: Just wanted to explicitly call out that as Ben wrote, you have to remove both the parenthesis AND the commas in the function call. This thread has additional details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell