# Error while calling function-Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'TriggerTime'

Tags: powershell

(commands like `Set-ScheduledTask` work only on Powershell v4.0 which has the "ScheduledTasks" module builtin)

I'm running the below code but receiving an error. Could someone please help me understand where the problem is.

```
SetScheduledTask : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'TriggerTime'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value 
of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.DateTime".
At C:\Users\skadithi\Desktop\Script.ps1:33 char:17
+ SetScheduledTask([datetime]$startFriday10PM,"QLAT_WinPatching_Friday_10PM")
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [SetScheduledTask], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,SetScheduledTask
```

**Code that receives user input and initializing dates for weekdays thereafter**

```
$startDate=Read-Host "Enter the StartDate in MM/DD/YYYY format"
$startDate=[datetime]$startDate

$startFriday=$startDate.AddDays(1)
$startFriday10PM=$startFriday.AddHours(22)
```

**Code to update**

```
Function UpdateScheduledTask
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [datetime]$TriggerTime,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$ScheduleName
     )
    if($TriggerTime -is [DateTime])
    {
        Write-Host "Running on $TriggerTime" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Event date must be a DateTime object" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    $Time = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $TriggerTime -Once
    Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $ScheduleName -Trigger $Time
}
```

**Calling the function**

```
UpdateScheduledTask($startFriday10PM,"QLAT_WinPatching_Friday_10PM")
```

Comment: After the error mesaages,text that appear as headings are comments from powershell script.All the text starting from the first heading is the actual code.

Comment: Function call is malformed. Should just be `UpdateScheduledTask $startFriday10PM "QLAT_WinPatching_Friday_10PM"`

Comment: Also since you are specifying the datatype of `$TriggerTime` there is not need to check to see what its type is. The function would fail otherwise.

Comment: Hi Matt,as you pointed out the function call i made was wrong.I got that corrected using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

This error means that parameter 'TriggerTime' need to be of System.DateTime type.

In your code:

```
$Time = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $TriggerTime -Once
```

New-ScheduledTaskTrigger returns a new scheduled task trigger object but you pass variable of type Object to -Trigger parameter

```
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $ScheduleName -Trigger $Time
```

which can take variables of System.DateTime type.

Comment: Hi Kostia,you make a very valid point and i was convinced about it too.However,the original issue was because of the wrong function call syntax that i made.I've updated the comments with the link that proved useful.And i continued using the $time variable for -Trigger parameter and surprisingly did not get any issues.Thanks for taking time to look into this and help.       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell