# Powershell function call in verbatim string

Tags: powershell

Is a function call in a verbatim PowerShell string a thing?

CSharp example:

```
$"this my { GetSomeValue() }";
```

I would rather not extract a variable if I don't have to.

Comment: Duplicate. "this is my $(GetResult($param))"

Answer (score 1):

I always do it this way:

```
$verbatimString = 'something' + (GetSomeValue) + 'end'
```

Since it's verbatim string, you cannot do any trick, to put value directly into it, like you showed in your example.
Remember to call functions without `()`, you can read about it here: [4988226](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)