# How do you pass multiple variables into a SQL script through powershell?

Tags: sql, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have the following line to set up my sql cmd.

```
    $mySqlCmd = "sqlcmd -S $server -U $username -P $pwd   -d $dbname -o $lis -i $sqlScript -v fileDate = $fileDate, filePath = $filePath, sqlLoadErrors = $sqlLoadErrorPath"
Invoke-Expression $mySqlCmd
```

This doesn't seem to work for more than one variable. The SQL script runs and works if I remove the last 2 variables I am trying to pass into the SQL script.

On my SQL script I have the following:

```
DECLARE 
    @currentDate NVARCHAR(25), 
    @filePath NVARCHAR(25),
    @sqlLoadErrors NVARCHAR(25)

SET @currentDate = $(fileDate) 
SET @filePath = $(filePath)
SET @sqlLoadErrors = $(sqlLoadErrors)
```

Is there something wrong being done in the powershell script to pass variables to an SQL script?

Comment: I'd bet the commas are confusing the parser.  I would try using PowerShell's stop parsing symbol, `--%`.  Like so: `$mySqlCmd = "sqlcmd --% -S $server -U $username -P $pwd   -d $dbname -o $lis -i $sqlScript -v fileDate = $fileDate, filePath = $filePath, sqlLoadErrors = $sqlLoadErrorPath"`.

Comment: Also, `$pwd` is a reserved variable name for the current working directory.  It's from the `pwd` POSIX shell command for "print working directory".   I'd avoid using that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the pwd tip though I changed that now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$cmdparameters = @(
    'fileDate = "17/06/2017"',
    'filePath = "c:\temp\test.txt"',
    'sqlLoadErrors = "yourcontent"'
)

$mySqlCmd = "sqlcmd -S $server -U $username -P $pwd   -d $dbname -o $lis -i $sqlScript -v $cmdparameters"
Invoke-Expression $mySqlCmd
```