# Cannot use parameter in SET clause of UPDATE query (Powershell, MS Access SQL)

Tags: sql, powershell, ms-access

Given this trivial Access database table:

```
ID   fruit   count
--   -----   -----
1    apples  10
2    oranges 2
```

My aim is to write a Powershell cmdlet (let's call it `Set-FruitCount`) that, given the name of a fruit, can set the count of that fruit. For example, the command `Set-FruitCount -Fruit Apples -Count 1` should update the row with ID 1 to set the count to 1. Of course my use case is more complicated, but I've tried to simplify the problem as far as possible for the sake of a clear question.

However, when trying to perform a parametrized update query, it does not work. However, hard-coding a specific value in almost the same query, just parametrizing the actual WHERE clause as opposed to the set clause, it does work.

This is my program:

```
$oConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\pvz\Documents\fruits.mdb"
$oConn.open()

function Get-Fruits {
    $TextInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
    $oCmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [fruits]", $oConn)
    $oReader = $oCmd.ExecuteReader()
    while ($oReader.Read()) {
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $oReader.FieldCount; $i++) {
            $Name = $TextInfo.ToTitleCase($oReader.GetName($i))
            $Value = $oReader[$i]
            $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $Name -Value $Value
        }
        $obj
    }
    $oReader.Close()
}

function Set-FruitCount {
    Param($Fruit, $Count)
    $strQuery = "UPDATE [fruits] SET [count] = @COUNT WHERE [fruit] = @FRUIT"
    $oCmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($strQuery, $oConn)
    [void]$oCmd.Parameters.Add("@FRUIT", $Fruit)
    [void]$oCmd.Parameters.Add("@COUNT", $Count)
    $ret = $oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Write-Host "Set-FruitCount affected $ret rows"
}

function Set-FruitCountToZero {
    Param($Fruit)
    $strQuery = "UPDATE [fruits] SET [count] = 0 WHERE [fruit] = @FRUIT"
    $oCmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($strQuery, $oConn)
    [void]$oCmd.Parameters.Add("@FRUIT", $Fruit)
    $ret = $oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Write-Host "Set-FruitCountToZero affected $ret rows"
}

Get-Fruits | Format-Table

Set-FruitCountToZero -Fruit "apples"
Get-Fruits | Format-Table

Set-FruitCount -Fruit "apples" -Count 1
Get-Fruits | Format-Table

$oConn.close()
```

And this is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\pvz\desktop> .\fruits.ps1

ID Fruit   Count
-- -----   -----
 1 apples     10
 2 oranges     2


Set-FruitCountToZero affected 1 rows

ID Fruit   Count
-- -----   -----
 1 apples      0
 2 oranges     2


Set-FruitCount affected 0 rows

ID Fruit   Count
-- -----   -----
 1 apples      0
 2 oranges     2


PS C:\Users\pvz\desktop>
```

As we can see, the `Set-FruitCountToZero` does work correctly, setting the count to zero, and affecting one row in the database. However, the `Set-FruitCount` function does not work, despite the only difference being one more parameter being added for the SET clause.

What am I missing?

(N.B. This question is regarding parametrized SQL queries, it has nothing to do with Powershell function parameters.)

Comment: Where are you setting the parameter value to zero?  (You said the only different is the existence of the paramaters?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)

Comment: @JacobH You are correct. Reversing the parameters gave me the desired result!

Comment: @ashleedawg This question is regarding parametrized SQL queries, it has nothing to do with Powershell function parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JacobH posted in a comment, it seems that OleDB is sensitive to the order parameters come in.

Therefore, here is the corrected version of ´Set-FruitCount` that does work:

```
function Set-FruitCount {
    Param($Fruit, $Count)
    $strQuery = "UPDATE [fruits] SET [count] = @COUNT WHERE [fruit] = @FRUIT"
    $oCmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($strQuery, $oConn)
    [void]$oCmd.Parameters.Add("@COUNT", $Count)
    [void]$oCmd.Parameters.Add("@FRUIT", $Fruit)
    $ret = $oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Write-Host "Set-FruitCount affected $ret rows"
}
```

Note that @COUNT and @FRUIT are now appearing in the same order as in the SQL query.