# Embedding parameters to a switch

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a .ps1 that calls down files and if it can't call down the files, it will look locally for those files. I'd like to give the option, as a parameter, to either work locally or go fetch from the internet and also specify which of the 5 files to use or call down. I'm made the script work with a "local" and "external" function, but how do I also add parameters to those functions?

For example:

```
./script.ps1 -local file1,file2,file3
```

or

```
./script.ps1 -external file4,file5
```

Here is my code currently:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=1)][string]$option
)

function RunLocal {
    Write-Host "local"
}
function RunExternal {
    Write-Host "ext"
}
function RunDefault {
    Write-Host "default"
}

switch ($option) {
    local    { RunLocal }
    external { RunExternal }
    default  { RunDefault }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)

Comment: You can try `./script.ps1 -option "local" file1,file2,file3` and `$option` will take the value `"local"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd define different [parameter sets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets/) and discriminate by parameter set name.

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='default')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='default', Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$Default,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='external', Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$External,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='local', Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$Local
)

# ...

switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    'local'    { RunLocal }
    'external' { RunExternal }
    'default'  { RunDefault }
}

# Usage:
# script.ps1 [-Default] 'file1', 'file2'
# script.ps1 -External 'file1', 'file2'
# script.ps1 -Local 'file1', 'file2'
```

Another option would be using separate parameters for option and file list, as [JPBlanc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637559/embedding-parameters-to-a-switch#comment92210491_52637559) suggested, but in that case you should [validate](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/02/04/using-powershell-parameter-validation-to-make-your-day-easier/) the `-Option` parameter, so that only allowed options can be used:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet('default', 'external', 'local')]
    [string]$Option,

    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$File
)

# ...

switch ($Option) {
    'local'    { RunLocal }
    'external' { RunExternal }
    'default'  { RunDefault }
}

# Usage:
# script.ps1 'default' 'file1', 'file2'
# script.ps1 -Option 'default' -File 'file1', 'file2'
# script.ps1 'external' 'file1', 'file2'
# script.ps1 -Option 'external' -File 'file1', 'file2'
# script.ps1 'local' 'file1', 'file2'
# script.ps1 -Option 'local' -File 'file1', 'file2'
```

Comment: Ok cool, so in the case of running a file, would I just make those a function? For example

`function RunLocal {

 function file1 {Write-Host "file1"}}`

Comment: @Hausec Why would you want to do that? That doesn't make any sense.