# passing a parameter in a function, the second parameter is always null

Tags: function, powershell

```
Function SCP-ImplementationFiles($selectedDirectory, $fileName) {


Write-Host $rdfFile.GetType() $rdfFile.Name       
SCP-ImplementationFiles($directoryPrompt, $rdfFile.Name)
```

My Write-Host is providing output

```
System.IO.FileInfo file1.pdf
```

However when I pass it to my function, the 2nd parameter is always empty/null

I defined the function as close to the top of the script (in case it matters)

Not a duplicate of [How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)

I am not trying to call a function from the prompt. I am trying to call the function from within the script. If I remove the ',' (comma), the editor tells me that there is a ',' missing

---

I've tried these functions to see if I did something wrong with the definition of my function

```
Function SCP-ImplementationFiles {
    param([string]$selectedDirectory, [string]$fileName)
    Write-Host $selectedDirectory
    Write-Host $fileName
}

Function SCP-ImplementationFiles([string]$selectedDirectory, [string]$fileName) {    
    Write-Host $selectedDirectory
    Write-Host $fileName
}

Function SCP-ImplementationFiles($selectedDirectory, $fileName) {    
    Write-Host $selectedDirectory
    Write-Host $fileName
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the body of the `SCP-ImplementationFiles` Function? It's difficult to get the full picture without it

Comment: Right now, I am just doing Write-Host and printing the parameters.

Comment: Is that your actual full function body? Could you add the closing `}`?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? How are you determining the value of `$fileName` is `$null`?

Comment: I mouse over when debugging and it says $fileName =. I can also see that the second parameter is a part of the 1st one (separated by a space)

Comment: You are passing an array using `SCP-ImplementationFiles ($directoryPrompt, $rdfFile.Name)`. Omit parentheses as well as any comma, call it as `SCP-ImplementationFiles $directoryPrompt $rdfFile.Name`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell) *I am not trying to call a function from the prompt. I am trying to call the function from within the script.* There is no difference between this two ways calling function.

Comment: You have to specify the parameter you want to send the data to. ex: `SCP-ImplementationFiles -selectedDirectory $directoryPrompt -fileName $rdfFile.Name`