# Alternatives to invoke-expression

Tags: powershell

I have this function:

```
function traced()
{
    write-host "$args"
    invoke-expression -Command "$args"
}
```

and I use it in several places like `traced cp "$($_.FullName)" (join-path $directory $newfile)` so that I have a log of all of the places that get copied (or removed, or whatever)

But when the directory contains spaces and dashes, it results in invoke-expression throwing.

I guess I could just define `traced-cp` and `traced-rm`, but if I have a lot of functions I want to trace, what's the generic answer? I just want a function that prints, then evaluates, the exact command its given. From what I understand, the `&` operator isn't what I want here-- It won't work for shell builtins.

Comment: Just turn on mandatory transcript logging on your machine! But the real question: Why do you want to use cmd builtins from PowerShell? :)

Comment: I want to use the powershell builtins, I just use the aliases cp and rm. But Start-Transcript looks like what I need, thanks!

Comment: If you're on Windows then there's also a policy setting you can use either locally or via GPO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] so that I have a log of all of the places that get copied (or removed, or whatever)

I'd strongly recommend you use transcript logging for this!

You can start a transcript interactively with the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet, but if you want to keep a transcript of every single instance of PowerShell you launch by default, I'd suggest turning it on by default!

Open the local policy editor (`gpedit.msc`) on your Windows box and navigate to:

- Computer Configuration

  - `>` Administrative Templates

    - `>` Windows Components

      - `>` Windows PowerShell

Select the policy setting named **"Turn on PowerShell Transcription"**, set it to **Enabled**, and optionally configure your preferred output directory (defaults to your home folder).

This way, you'll always have a full transcript of your interactions in PowerShell :)

Answer (score 1):

[Consider using argument splatting to build your command instead of building a string-based command with `Invoke-Expression`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485284/584676) I also don't know where you heard that `&` doesn't work with shell built-ins but it works with both commands and cmdlets.

[Here is the official Microsoft documentation on splatting in Powershell.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6)

This approach also eliminates the difficulty in crafting a command string correctly, having to escape characters, and dealing with path spaces - using splatting with named or positional arguments takes care of most of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using -verbose with copy-item or remove-item, and also -passthru with copy-item.