# How to pipe wget results to subsequent curl post?

Tags: powershell, curl, windows-10, wget

I am in Windows 10 attempting to get Confluent CE up via docker.  See their instructions [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/cos-docker-quickstart.html#step-3-install-a-ak-connector-and-generate-sample-data).

The trouble is I believe these are specifically for MAC OS, and Windows requires slightly different syntax for the following command:

```
wget https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen/raw/master/config/connector_pageviews_cos.config
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @connector_pageviews_cos.config http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

I think I am supposed to be piping the wget results to the curl.  How to do that in Windows 10 ?

The powershell exception:

```
At line:1 char:57
+ ... ntent-Type: application/json" --data @connector_pageviews_cos.config ...
+                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@connector_pageviews_cos' can be
used only as an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$connector_pageviews_cos'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `curl` and `wget` are aliased in Powershell 5.1 to `Invoke-WebRequest`, although it seems that `curl.exe` is available under `System32` (and is available in place of an alias in Powershell Core). But, it's not too difficult to translate both calls to the Powershell-native `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet.

Your `wget` call becomes:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen/raw/master/config/connector_pageviews_cos.config -Outfile connector_pageviews_cos.config
```

And your `curl` call becomes:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:8083/connectors -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body (Get-Content -Raw connector_pageviews_cos.config)
```

If desired, **you can combine both calls into a single line**, as the `-Body` parameter accepts pipeline input:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen/raw/master/config/connector_pageviews_cos.config |
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:8083/connectors -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Omit the `-OutFile` parameter on the first `Invoke-WebRequest`, which outputs the payload contents to the pipeline. You then pipe that output into the second `Invoke-WebRequest` while providing other positional and named arguments as needed.

[More information on `Invoke-WebRequest` is available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-WebRequest), and you would also do well to check out the convenient-to-use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod) which makes working with RESTful APIs much more comfortable.

---

As a note, the `@` operator is used for a concept called [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) in Powershell, which explains the error you were receiving. Read the link above for more information, and elsewhere [I've also written an answer on how to use splatting to pass arguments to cmdlets and commands.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485284/584676)

Comment: Yes. I did start to gather as much about the Invoke-WebRequest, and also read about this "splatting".  It appears that the results of these commands would leave that config file behind.  Is there a way to pipe the out of such from first cmd to become the input of the second?  (Just curious!)  The results being that I would end up with the post and no residual file to clean up.  Thanks!  I will try this out...

Comment: Yes, I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Thanks!  It's a good answer.  Moved me forward slightly in the struggle to get a test Confluent environment running via Docker in a Windows 10 OS...