# VBScript not running from windows service

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript

I have a Windows service which calls a bat file. That bat file calls a PowerShell script, and inside that PowerShell script a VBScript is called.

```
Windows Service > bat file > powershell file > vbscript
```

When I manually run the bat file, the VBscript is successfully executed, but if I execute the same bat file from the Windows service, then all scripts are called, but the VBScript skips to run.

Executing a bat file manually successfully executes the VBScript, but not via Windows service

I tried to call The VBScript inside PowerShell in different ways:

1. `& c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe NameOfFile.vbs`
2. `start-process`
3. `invoke-expression`
4. `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe NameOfFiles.vbs //B //Nologo $IP_SU $RemoteSessions_Output $user`

My VBScript is:

```vb
dim ip
dim sessions_dir
dim temp
dim username
dim password

set temp = Wscript.Arguments
ip = temp(0)
sessions_dir = temp(1)
username = temp(2)
password = temp(3)

Sub WaitEnter()
    WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip )
    WScript.Sleep 2000
    WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip)
    WshShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"
    WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip)
    WScript.Sleep 2000
End Sub

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Wscript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip )
WshShell.Run "telnet " & ip & " -f " & sessions_dir & "\" & ip & "_SU_Status_Output.txt",2
WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip)
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip)
WshShell.SendKeys username
WaitEnter

WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip)
WshShell.SendKeys password
WaitEnter

WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip)
WshShell.SendKeys "SU_INrOmk=` pl | awk '{{}print {$}3{}}' | head -3 | cut -d '=' -f2`; SU_type=` pl | grep $SU_INrOmk | tail -1 | awk '{{}print {$}12{}}'`"
WaitEnter

WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip)
WshShell.SendKeys "echo $SU_type"
WaitEnter

WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip)
WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
WshShell.AppActivate("telnet " & ip)
WshShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"
```

and PowerShell script from where it is called is like:

```
if(Test-Path C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe){
    echo "Cscript found"
    $command = "& C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe NameOfFile.vbs $IP_SU $RemoteSessions_Output $user $DecPwd | out-null"
    Invoke-Expression -Command $Command
    start-Sleep 10
    if($?){
        start-sleep 10
        $SU_Output_File = $IP_SU + "_SU_Status_Output.txt"
        $SU_Remote_FilePath = $RemoteSessions_Output + "\" + $SU_Output_File
    }
}
```

i expect that VBScript is called when Windows service calls the bat file.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: `Windows Service -> Batch File -> PowerShell -> VBScript`. Just one question, why??

Comment: Do you need to specify the full path to your vbs file?  Or at least set a working directory?  Either specify the full path, or perhaps something like: Start-Process -FilePath "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe" -ArgumentList "NameOfFile.vbs" -WorkingDirectory "c:\path\to\vbs"...

Answer (score 0):

I see several things that could be causing issues for you here.

I'm no master of VBS, but my guess here is that you are using `Wscript` which requires interactivity I think, but you should be using `Cscript` variant calls instead. My guess is that your script may be bombing due to this. Services can not run in an interactive context since Vista/Windows Server 2008.

You are calling this with `Invoke-Expression`, which ***(almost) always returns successful even if the cmdlet failed***. In other words, `Invoke-Expression` will (almost) always set `$?` to $True even if the command failed. However, you can slip in an evaluation of `; $?` at the end of your expression which will end up setting `$?` as you would expect, which breaks the notion of "always sets `$?` to `$True`".

However, you are also using `$?` incorrectly as well. `$?` only evaluates the success of `cmdlets`, not commands. `cscript.exe` is an executable, and must have its success evaluated with the `$LASTEXITCODE` automatic variable instead. This will be typically be `0` for success and any other value for non-success. You will have to check the success of this `$LASTEXITCODE` yourself, as even when the `ErrorActionPreference` is set to `Stop`, it won't automatically treat non-zero exit codes as terminating errors.

Outside of the scope of this answer, but worth a mention, [I would recommend replacing `Invoke-Expression` with a straight call to the executable and splat your parameters instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485284/584676).

Comment: Thanks Bender for replying, but i didn't get the first para. i am using cscript only and not the wscript. i am newbie to vbscript and telnet, please let me know which code line shows that i am using wscript and not cscript.

Comment: Line 7 of your vbs is the first occurrence I see