# powershell function: why more values are returned?

Tags: function, powershell, return-value

Good Morning everybody,
i'm writing my firts ps script:
a function with 3 input string and a returned output string but something sound strange for me:
this is my code:

```
function MyLogger($MyString, $MyFileName, $MyFilePath)
{

    $FullLogFile = ($MyFilePath +"\"+ $MyFileName)
    $DateForLog =  Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
    $LogRow = ($DateForLog + " " + $MyString)
    return $LogRow
}

$LogFile = "logname.txt"

$dir = "C:\psscript\workingwithfiles"

$mystr = "stringgggg"

$ret = MyLogger($mystr, $LogFile, $dir)

Write-Host "***************print function res**************"

Write-Host $ret

Write-Host "***************end print function res**************"
```

why function output (return $LogRow) is this:

```
2020-01-28 13:11:03 stringgggg logname.txt C:\psscript\workingwithfiles
```

and not only this?

```
2020-01-28 13:11:03 stringgggg
```

Full output:

```
***************print function res**************

2020-01-28 13:11:03 stringgggg logname.txt C:\psscript\workingwithfiles

***************end print function res**************
```

Thank's everybody

Comment: Arguments passed to PowerShell commands should be separated by spaces, not commas. Change `MyLogger($mystr, $LogFile, $dir)` to `MyLogger $mystr $LogFile $dir`

Comment: Take a look here [Parameters in Functions PS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen - Thank you so much, didn't know that, it's my first script ever and i have to end it this evening so i just copied from the internet, i don't have time to study it... Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Better use PowerShell syntax:

```
function MyLogger
{
    param(  [string]$MyString, 
            [string]$MyFileName, 
            [string]$MyFilePath)


    $FullLogFile = ($MyFilePath +"\"+ $MyFileName)
    $DateForLog =  Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
    $LogRow = ($DateForLog + " " + $MyString)
    return $LogRow
}

$LogFile = "logname.txt"

$dir = "C:\psscript\workingwithfiles"

$mystr = "stringgggg"

$ret = MyLogger -MyString $mystr -MyFileName $LogFile -MyFilePath $dir

Write-Host "***************print function res**************"

Write-Host $ret

Write-Host "***************end print function res**************"
```