# How to separate variable in a variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell

This is my code with PHP that passes a variable to a PowerShell script.

```
Param([string]$username,[string]$pass)

write-output ("username $username password $pass")
```

The output if I insert username:sam and pass:123 is:

```
username sam123 password
```

I want it to be like this:

```
username sam password 123
```

How can you do this?

Comment: You don't show how the PowerShell code is being invoked from PHP, but I suspect the problem may be that parameters are being passed with `,` as the separator instead of _spaces_, which is what PowerSell requires: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988239/45375

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
"Username:{0} Password:{1}" -f $username , $pass
```