# PowerShell Question on Printing Variables inside of Strings

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell.

```
function weekendplans($a,$b,$c)
{
    $message = "This is a $a $b and an $c"
    $message
}
weekendplans("pear", "apple", "orange")
```

When I run this code the output I get is `This is a pear apple orange  and an`

I know that I can simply use the string format to fix this but I was curious why this was happening in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Calling a function like that puts all of the contents in an array variable. Call the function like @TheGameiswar's answer or like `weekendplans("pear")("apple")("Orange")` you can also use `weekendplans -a "apple" -b "pear" -c "orange"`

Comment: Comma delimited calling of the function would be making an array as var `$a` like in your question.

Answer (score 4):

you should call like below

```
function weekendplans($a,$b,$c)
{
$message = "This is a $a $b and an $($c)"
$message
}
weekendplans "pear" "apple" "orange"
```

with the way you passed, all arguments are assigned  to `$a`

```
function weekendplans($a,$b,$c)
{

Write-Host "a is $a"
Write-host "b is $b"
Write-host "c is $c"

$message = "This is a $a $b and an $c"
$message
}
```

> ```
> PS C:\> weekendplans("pear", "apple", "orange")
> ```

running above gives me

```
a is pear apple orange
b is 
c is 
This is a pear apple orange  and an
```

Correct way to Pass Parameters in power shell is through space separated and not by comma

if you are not aware, you can call `.NetClasses` in powershell ,they are called comma seperated.Below is one example

```
[System.DateTime]::DaysInMonth(2020,6)
```

Parenthesised arguments are used in .NET methods only

> Parameters in calls to functions in PowerShell (all versions) are space-separated, not comma separated. Also, the parentheses are entirely unneccessary and will cause a parse error in PowerShell 2.0 (or later) if Set-StrictMode is active. Parenthesised arguments are used in .NET methods only.

**Further reading and References:**

[How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

Along with @TheGameiswar's answer, you can take a poor man's debug approach, using variable squeezing to assign to a variable and output to screen at the same time. So, step into what you are trying one segment at a time...

```
function weekendplans($a,$b,$c)
{
($message = "This is a $a $b and an $c")
}
weekendplans('pear', 'apple', 'orange')
<#
# Results

The function or command was called as if it were a method. 
Parameters should be separated by spaces. 
For information about parameters, see the about_Parameters 

Help topic.
At line:6 char:1
+ weekendplans('pear', 'apple', 'orange')
...
#>

function weekendplans($a,$b,$c)
{
($message = "This is a $a $b and an $c")
}
weekendplans 'pear', 'apple', 'orange'
<#
# Results

This is a pear apple orange  and an 
#>

function weekendplans($a,$b,$c)
{
    ($message = "This is a $a")
    ($message = "This is a $b")
    ($message = "This is a $c")
}
weekendplans 'pear', 'apple', 'orange'
<#
# Results

This is a pear apple orange
This is a 
This is a 
#>

function weekendplans($a,$b,$c)
{
    ($message = "This is a $a")
    ($message = "This is a $b")
    ($message = "This is a $c")
}
weekendplans 'pear' 'apple' 'orange'
<#
# Results

This is a pear
This is a apple
This is a orange
#>
```