# Call a Powershell script function from CMD with parameters

Tags: function, powershell, batch-file, command-line, parameters

Maybe i need a pair of fresh eyes on that:

i use the following code in a .bat file in order to call a Powershell script which accepts 2 parameters.And i want to pass the same parameters in a function which is the Powershell script.The problem is that i cannot seperate the 2 parameters inside the function.Here is the code inside the .bat file :

```
@ECHO OFf
Set OUTFILE="C:\users\XXX\desktop\newchangepass\log.txt"

echo user='%1' pass='%2' >> %OUTFILE%

echo %1 %2

"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -File "C:\ps\CallMeWithParams.ps1" %1 %2
```

That's what i give to the command line:

```
c:\PS>CallMeWithParams.bat Alpha Beta
```

and here is the code inside the Powershell script:

```
param ([Parameter (Mandatory)]$param1, [Parameter(Mandatory)]$param2 )
function foo{
    param ($fusername,$fpassword)
    write-output $fusername

}
foo($param1,$param2)
```

The output which i receive obviously in CMD is:

```
c:\PS>CallMeWithParams.bat Alpha Beta
Alpha Beta
Alpha
Beta
```

i should get only the first parameter....

The code inside the PS script is there for test reasons.I want to be sure that i get the two parameters and that i can seperate them in order to use the second one in an update statement.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
PS1: Yes the CMD arguments will be enclosed in double quotes
PS2: atm there is no control on variable types etc. I wanted to keep it simple for debugging reasons.

Comment: Change `foo($param1,$param2)` to `foo -fusername $param1 -fpassword $param2` in the last line of the script

Comment: Mathias is right - the reason is `$fpassword` is not mandatory, so you're just running `foo` twice with the first parameter only. The parentheses creates a single list object

Comment: @user19702 No, the code calls `foo` only once, but passes an array consisting of `$param1` and `$param2` for parameter `-fusername`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)

Comment: Thank you very much Mathias, that was it!