# Powershell Functions doesn't take parameters properly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I just want to create a new directory named with a date an hour. And I want to copy something from another directory to new created directory. Like a back-up operation.

Well I'm new learner about powershell. I've tried to read all docs from microsoft. But I clearly don't understand what am I missing?

So my script is like this without a function block and it's working:

```
     if (Test-Path -Path "$pathBackup\$finalDate") {
       Remove-Item $pathBackup\$finalDate -Recurse -Force         
    }
 New-Item -Path $pathBackup -Name $finalDate -ItemType Directory
 [string]$backupDirectory = "$pathApplication\*"
 [string]$backupDestination = "$pathBackup$backupDate"
 Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $backupDirectory -Destination $backupDestination
```

But When I try this steps in a function block. For a modular struct. Because I want to use this function with different parameters. So my function is like this: and it's not working.

```
function createDir ($pathName, $folderName){ 

 if ((Test-Path -Path "$path$folderName")) {

     Remove-Item "$path$folderName" -Recurse -Force

 }

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $pathName -Name $folderName 
[string]$backupSource = "$pathApplication\*"
[string]$backupDestination = "$pathName$folderName"
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $backupSource -Destination $backupDestination
 }
```

I think the ps reads my variables as a System.Object but I should use String. But I don't know how to do

I'm calling the function like this:

```
  createDir($pathBackup, $finalDate)
```

And Powershell doesn't recognize pathBackup and finalDate variables. Instead of this ps creates a folder which is named **System.Object[]** in location of powershell scripts path.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show how 1) the function is called, and 2) what exactly happens then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i would suggest to use the following parameter notation (but this is just personal preference). It would be interessting how you call the function. Do you even call the funciton ? Maybe its not working because you forgot to call the function ?

```
function createDir {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    pathName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    folderName,
 )

if ((Test-Path -Path "$path\$folderName")) {##Here is a missing backslash

     Remove-Item "$path\$folderName" -Recurse -Force ##Also here

 }

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $pathName -Name $folderName 
[string]$backupSource = "$pathApplication\*"
[string]$backupDestination = "$pathName$folderName"
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $backupSource -Destination $backupDestination

 }
}
    ##FunctionCall
    createDir -pathName "C:\Test2\" -folderName "Test1"
```

EDIT: It seems your function call is the problem.
[image]

Take a look in this article: [StackOverflow How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)

You should call your function like:

```
createDir -pathName $pathBackup -folderName $finalDate
```

Comment: I edited the function as you said and tried to call it as you said, but this time I got the following error:  A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-'.     As you said, I have some deficiencies in the functions part, I think I'd better review and learn it properly.

Comment: No `$` in the parameter names when calling the function.

Comment: @notjustme. You are right. My bad. I copy pasted the variable names and forgot to remoe the $ ;) Now you should be good to go. Try again. Sorry :)

Comment: createDir -pathName $pathBackup -folderName $finalDate I think this one is right.

Comment: @LKo.exp I'm not the OP, just spotted the error. :)

Comment: @notjustme. Yeah i know ;) Thank you for spotting the mistake :)
OP (eagerdev) should try again with updated syntax :)

Comment: With the uncertainty of whether or not `$path` contains a trailing "\" I would suggest the use of `Join-Path` rather than simple string manipulation...