# Function of argument array

Tags: powershell

Hy everybody, could someone explain to me why this happens?

```
$Script = {"My name is $($ARGS[0]) and my surname is $($ARGS[1])"} 



& $SCRIPT "CARL","WHITE"
```

Output expected: MY name is CARL and my surname is WHITE

Actual output: My name is CARL WHITE and my surname is

that's because $args[0] is an array itself, this means that I should change the script like this:

```
$Script = {"My name is $($ARGS[0][0]) and my surname is $($ARGS[0][1])"}
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4988226/45375

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you only provide 1 argument - an array consisting of the two string literals `CARL` and `WHITE`.

Remove the `,` and PowerShell will bind the two strings as two separate arguments instead:

```
& $Script "CARL" "WHITE"
```

Comment: thanks! I should have tried days long to understand this by my own!