# powershell select-object expression with a function with parameters

Tags: powershell, select-object

how can i pass 2 parameters to a function in an expression?

```
function somefunkystuff ($p1, $p2)
{
    #both passed values are available, just not as expected
    #why are the parameters in the calling Expression passed to $p1 as an array instead of just to both parameters $p1 and $p2?
    #return $p1.ToString() + $p2.ToString() # doesn't work as expected

    return $p1[0].ToString() + $p1[1].ToString()
    
}
$a = [PSCustomObject]@{MyName="jef"; Number=1}
$b = [PSCustomObject]@{MyName="john"; Number=2}
$c = [PSCustomObject]@{MyName="jonas"; Number=3}

@($a, $b, $c) | Select-Object MyName, Number, @{Name="NameId"; Expression={ somefunkystuff( $_.MyName, $_.Number) }}
```

Comment: Don't use brackets around the parameters for your function and also remove the comma in between: `Expression={ somefunkystuff $_.MyName $_.Number}}`, then just have it return the values `$p1` and `$p2`

Comment: In short: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see: [How do I pass multiple parameters into a function in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell)

and change your code to:

- `return $p1[0].ToString() + $p1[1].ToString()` changed to `return $p1 + $p2`
- `Expression={ somefunkystuff( $_.MyName, $_.Number) }` change to `Expression={ somefunkystuff $_.MyName $_.Number }`

```
function somefunkystuff ($p1, $p2)
{
    #both passed values are available, just not as expected
    #why are the parameters in the calling Expression passed to $p1 as an array instead of just to both parameters $p1 and $p2?
    #return $p1.ToString() + $p2.ToString() # doesn't work as expected

    return $p1 + $p2
    
}
$a = [PSCustomObject]@{MyName="jef"; Number=1}
$b = [PSCustomObject]@{MyName="john"; Number=2}
$c = [PSCustomObject]@{MyName="jonas"; Number=3}

@($a, $b, $c) | Select-Object MyName, Number, @{Name="NameId"; Expression={ somefunkystuff  $_.MyName $_.Number }}
```

output:

```
MyName Number NameId
------ ------ ------
jef         1 jef1
john        2 john2
jonas       3 jonas3
```

Comment: thank you  (certainly for the reference to the other post!)