# file IO, is this a bug in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, filestream

I have the following code in Powershell

```
$filePath = "C:\my\programming\Powershell\output.test.txt"

try
{
    $wStream = new-object IO.FileStream $filePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Append, [IO.FileAccess]::Write, [IO.FileShare]::Read

    $sWriter = New-Object  System.IO.StreamWriter $wStream

    $sWriter.writeLine("test")
 }
```

I keep getting error:

> Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "[IO.FileMode]::Append", for
>   "FileStream" to type "System.IO.FileMode": "Cannot convert value
>   "[IO.FileMode]::Append" to type "System.IO.FileMode" due to invalid
>   enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumeration values
>   and try again. The possible enumeration values are "CreateNew, Create,
>   Open, OpenOrCreate, Truncate, Append"."

I tried the equivalent in C#,

```
    FileStream fStream = null;
    StreamWriter stWriter = null;

    try
    {
        fStream = new FileStream(@"C:\my\programming\Powershell\output.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
        stWriter = new StreamWriter(fStream);
        stWriter.WriteLine("hahha");
    }
```

it works fine!

What's wrong with my powershell script? BTW I am running on powershell

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      2      0      2237
```

Comment: The enums are parsed as strings! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289573/passing-enum-values-to-a-function-in-powershell

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Another way would be to use just the name of the value and let PowerShell cast it to the target type:

```
New-Object IO.FileStream $filePath ,'Append','Write','Read'
```

Comment: I can't believe powershell cannot handle an enum in a constructor. They are on version 5.1 now and this still doesn't work!

Answer (score 9):

When using the `New-Object` cmdlet and the target type constructor takes in parameters, you should either use the `-ArgumentList` parameter (of New-Object) or wrap the parameters in parenthesis - I prefer to wrap my constructors with parens:

```
# setup some convenience variables to keep each line shorter
$path = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($Env:TEMP,"Temp.txt")
$mode = [System.IO.FileMode]::Append
$access = [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write
$sharing = [IO.FileShare]::Read

# create the FileStream and StreamWriter objects
$fs = New-Object IO.FileStream($path, $mode, $access, $sharing)
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($fs)

# write something and remember to call to Dispose to clean up the resources
$sw.WriteLine("Hello, PowerShell!")
$sw.Dispose()
$fs.Dispose()
```

New-Object cmdlet online help: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113355

Comment: You can equally well leave out the parens, because it just expects an object array, optionally preceded by `-ArgumentList`. Your parens just make it a separate expression; is that correct?

Comment: Parens around an array in PowerShell is effectively a no-op except to act as a token separator.  I avoid this syntax `new-object <typename>(arg,arg,...)` because it misleads you into believing this is just a C# constructor when it really isn't.  It's actually less typing to use `new-object <typename> arg,arg,...`.  Sorry for being pedantic but I've answered too many questions about why `MyPowerShellFunctionThatTakesThreeParameters(1,2,3)` doesn't work.  :-)

Comment: The powershell decision makers are starting to get on my nerves.  One day you're not supposed to use parerenthesis. The next day you are. I see you're using commas for constructors too now. They made this more difficult than it needed to be.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way could be to enclose the enums in parens:

```
$wStream = new-object IO.FileStream $filePath, ([System.IO.FileMode]::Append), `
    ([IO.FileAccess]::Write), ([IO.FileShare]::Read)
```

Comment: Your way would work if you use parentheses while constructing the FileStream: $wStream = new-object IO.FileStream $filePath([System.IO.FileMode]::Append, [IO.FileAccess]::Write, [IO.FileShare]::Read)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to write into a logfile or text file, then you could try the supported cmdlets in PowerShell to achieve this?

```
Get-Help Out-File -Detailed
```