# StreamReader Correct way to read whole file without locking a file?

Tags: .net, powershell, streamreader

I am trying to read out of a license file written in xml in a way that will not lock the file in case the application happens to check at the same time. I have based the below code off of these two answers from [Shay Levy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294055/file-io-is-this-a-bug-in-powershell) and [Jb Evain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606349/can-i-prevent-a-streamreader-from-locking-a-text-file-whilst-it-is-in-use)

I have confirmed that this is able to read from the file needed, and elements are able to be accessed and read from, but I wanted to confirm if reading the file in this way will not cause any file locking issues?

```
$FileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $Path, 'Open', 'Read', 'ReadWrite'
$StreamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($FileStream)

$ReadFile = [xml] $StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: To confirm that, I'd suggest putting a long sleep / key press or whatever in the middle, and *try opening the file somewhere else*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [access and share mode compatibility table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/creating-and-opening-files). It is for the Win32 API, but applies to .NET as well because it calls down to Win32 `CreateFile` for file system access.

In your case the 3rd row applies (it contains a formatting error, which I've fixed below):

| First call to CreateFile | Valid second calls to CreateFile |
| --- | --- |
| GENERIC_READ FILE_SHARE_READ FILE_SHARE_WRITE | - GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ - GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE - GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ - GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE - GENERIC_READ, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ - GENERIC_READ, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE |

Assuming **your script opens the file first**, file locking issues can happen in these cases:

- If another application tries to open the file without specifying *any* share mode flags, it will fail.
- If another application tries to open the file with `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` only, it will fail (regardless of open mode). Other applications need to specify either `FILE_SHARE_READ` or `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` to successfully open the file.

On the other hand, if the file has been **opened by another application first**, your attempt at opening the file will fail if:

- The other application didn't specify *any* share mode flags.
- The other application has opened the file with `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` only. Other applications need to specify either `FILE_SHARE_READ` or `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` to let your script successfully open the file afterwards.

**Conclusion:**

- Specifying file share mode `ReadWrite` is the best you can do to ensure maximum compatibility when you need to read the file.